# XFDL Date Constraints

Tags: xforms, xfdf

I have a form, and on the form it requires a date. The date must be on YYYY-MM-DD format and be on or after 2022-04-01.
I am using XFDL and XForms. The only ref I can find in the source code for date is,

`<xforms:bind nodeset="instance('INSTANCE')/CertificatonDt" constraint=".='' or substring(., 1, 4) = '2020'" required="true()">`

Do I just change the 2020 to 2022?

Answer (score 1):

Yes! Using XPath 1.0, the substring() fonction will extract the year from the string representing it.

The current expression is just allowing 2020 as year. If you need a more sophisticated test, you have to replace it with something like `. = '' or (number(substring(., 1, 4)) = 2022 and number(substring(., 6, 2)) >= 4) or number(substring(., 1, 4)) > 2022`

Comment: Thank you!!! That worked!!

Comment: So, I know I said "That worked", but I've come back to the form and when I put in a date after 2022/04 it is showing that there is an error on the form.  By error I mean in the viewer mode it turn the entry field box red, indicating that the date is not acceptable.

Here is what I have for the code...

<xforms:bind nodeset="instance('INSTANCE')/CertificatonDt"
                            constraint=".='' or (number(substring(., 1, 4)) >= '2022' and number(substring(., 6, 2)) >= '4')"
                            required="true()"/>

Comment: I edited the previous answer to allow 2023-01-01, for example